# Is the Kantorovich duality only for 1-Wasserstein?

Tags: duality-theorems, optimal-transport

I’m reading this paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.07642.pdf), and the authors make the following assertion:

“Unfortunately, their algorithm cannot be readily applied to any other OT cost, because the famous Kantorovich duality holds only for W1”

So, they claim that the Kantorovich Duality is valid only for the 1-Wasserstein distance. I think they are actually speaking of the Kantorovich-Rubinstein duality. But is it really only valid for the 1-Wasserstein?

Comment: Can you give definitions for $W_1$ and the Kantorovich duality? Because with the definitions I'm familiar this is clear: if the Kantorovich duality would hold for $W_1$ and $W_p$ where $p > 1$, then it would follow that $W_1 = W_p$.

Comment: The claim is not true in full generality (I ignore the setting of the paper for which it might hold). Carmona & Delarue prove the Kantorovich duality theorem in their first volume of their "Probabilistic Theory of MFG". It is there the proposition 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are referring to the Kantorovich-Rubinstein duality. The paper they reference involves using neural networks to approximate the Lipschitz potentials.

In general (with suitable assumptions on $c$, especially for powers of the euclidean norm) you have the duality
$$ \inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu,\nu)} \int_{X \times Y} c(x,y) d \pi = \sup_{\substack{\varphi \in C_0(X) \\ \varphi(x) + \varphi^c(y) \leq c(x,y)} }\int_X \varphi d\mu + \int_Y \varphi^c d\nu $$
where
$$ \varphi^c(y) = \inf_x c(x,y) - \varphi(x) $$
for a reference you can see *Santambrogio's* Optimal Transport for Applied Mathematicians - Chapter 1.2.

In the case of $c(x,y) = d(x,y)$, this reduces to lipschitz functions since $\varphi^c = - \varphi$.